# How to handle it block when it performs testing on async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I am trying to test the async function inside **it** block. But, it always throws me a warning stating-> **Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed**. I also referred a similar question on stack overflow but it does not solve my issue. I also tried with `npm test -- --detectOpenHandles`(not works either).

user_model.js
​

```
static async createUser(req_body) {
        return {
            user_full_name: req_body.user_full_name,
            user_email: req_body.user_email,
            user_password: await bcrypt.hash(req_body.user_password, await bcrypt.genSalt(10)),
            user_phone: req_body.user_phone,
            user_account_created_date: new Date(),
            user_account_last_modified: new Date(),
            user_status: await userSchema.user_status.default(),
            user_permission_level: await userSchema.user_permission_level.default()
        };
    }
```

user_model.test.js
​

```
describe("Create User Object", () => {
    const User = {
        user_full_name: "abcd",
        user_email: "abcd@xyz.com",
        user_password: "abcd$123",
        user_phone: "1234567891"
    };
​
    it("should return a User Object with hashed password", () => {      
​
        return UserModel.createUser(User).then(result => {
            expect(result.user_password).not.toEqual(User.password);
        });
​
    });
})
```

Comment: no need of `done` when you are returning a promise, so just remove `async` when not using `await` also `done` from the param.

Comment: yes, i have removed async, but still it shows the same warning @AZ_

Comment: can you test with a catch block?

Comment: can you please suggest me how to frame try catch for this test case. @AZ_

Comment: `return UserModel.createUser(User).then(......).catch(err => expect not to get error)` this should not be the issue, as you are not getting the rejected promise error still give it a try.

Comment: tried with your suggestion, but still problem persist @AZ_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196614/discussion-between-hari-prasanth-and-az).

Answer (score 0):

Please try calling done(); like below.

```
describe("Create User Object", () => {
const User = {
    user_full_name: "abcd",
    user_email: "abcd@xyz.com",
    user_password: "abcd$123",
    user_phone: "1234567891"
};
it("should return a User Object with hashed password", done => {      
    UserModel.createUser(User).then(result => {
        expect(result.user_password).not.toEqual(User.password);
        done();
    });
});
})
```

Comment: Can you please share userSchema mock?

Comment: i am validating the createUser() by passing a dummy data user. i am not creating any mock.

Comment: Can you please try : ```user_password: bcrypt.hash(req_body.user_password, bcrypt.genSalt(10))```

Comment: tried by removing async. but still the propblem persist

Answer (score 0):

You missed to call done, below code will work. I would suggest removing async and done from test case and it will work

```
describe("Create User Object", () => {
    const User = {
        user_full_name: "abcd",
        user_email: "abcd@xyz.com",
        user_password: "abcd$123",
        user_phone: "1234567891"
    }; ​
    it("should return a User Object with hashed password",(done) => {       ​
        return UserModel.createUser(User).then(result => {
        expect(result.user_password).not.toEqual(User.password); 
        done();
       });  })
```

Comment: Have you tried removing async and done from test case

Answer (score 0):

Just try it with async/await syntax as well

```
describe("Create User Object", () => {
    const User = {
        user_full_name: "abcd",
        user_email: "abcd@xyz.com",
        user_password: "abcd$123",
        user_phone: "1234567891"
    };
​
    it("should return a User Object with hashed password", async () => {      
​
        const result = await UserModel.createUser(User)

        expect(result.user_password).not.toEqual(User.password);
    });
})
```